# JS element label with special character

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm trying to disable some form fields if the logged user doesn't have permission to edit the fields.  I had it working fine until I tried to do some browser compatibility testing and found that using JQuery to do

```
$("#id_first_name").attr('disabled', true);
[etc. fields]
```

doesn't work for IE.  I started going through and replacing those with

```
id_first_name.disabled = true;
```

which does work, but I've run into a snag.  A couple of my fields are labeled with a -, which causes a 'ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side' error.

It looks like it worked fine in jQuery because the label was in quotes, but I need a solution that doesn't use jQuery and without changing the label of those fields.  Please advise, without success I've tried:

```
id_security-email.disabled = true;
'id_security-email'.disabled = true;
id_security\-email.disabled = true;
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('id_security-email').disabled=true;` ?

Answer (score 1):

You really should be setting the "disabled" **property**, not the attribute.

```
$("#id_security-email").prop("disabled", true);
```

Alternatively, your attempts to reference the global property could also be done like this:

```
window["id_security-email"].disabled = true;
```

Yet another option:

```
document.getElementById("id_security-email").disabled = true;
```

Comment: ... though I *thought* jQuery has code to avoid setting things like the "disabled" attribute to the string "true" ...

Comment: I'm running jQuery 1.5, before .prop() was introduced.

Comment: @SirDeimos good grief that's over 3 years old.  Well in that case the old `.attr()` should work; what makes you think it's not? In what browser(s) does it fail?